# Why doesn't my test run tearDownAfterTestClass when it fails

Tags: selenium, phpunit

in a test i am writing the `setUpBeforeTests` creates a new customer in the database who is then used to perform the tests with so naturally when i finish the test i should get rid of this test customer in `tearDownAfterTestClass` so that i can create then anew when i rerun the test and not get any false positives

how when the tests all run fine i have no problem but if a test fails and i go to rerun it my `setUpBeforeTests` fails because i check for mysql errors in it like this

```
try
{
    if(!mysqli_query($connection,$query))
    {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
catch (Exception $exc)
{
    $msg = '[tearDownAfterTestClass] Exception Error' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= 'Could not run query - '.mysqli_error($connection). PHP_EOL;;
    $this->fail($msg);
}
```

the error i get is that there is a primary key violation which is expected cause i'm trying to create a new customer using the same data (primary key is on email which is also used to log in) however that means when the test failed it didn't run `tearDownAfterTestClass`

now i could just move everything in `tearDownAfterTestClass` to the start of `setUpBeforeTests` however to me that seems like bad programming since it defeates the purpose of even have `tearDownAfterTestClass`

so i am wondering, why isn't my `tearDownAfterTestClass` running when a test fails

NOTE: the database is a fundamental part of the system i'm testing and the database and system are on a separate development environment not the live one, the backup files for the database are almost 2 GBs and takes almost 1/2 an hour to restore, the purpose of the tear down is to remove any data we have added because of the test so that we don't have to restore the database every time we run the tests

Comment: When done correctly, you delete the whole database after the tests, and probably ensure it is deleted when starting the tests as well. So this is would then be no issue because you started with an empty or maybe pre-filled database.

Comment: @Sven why would I even think of deleting the entire database just for a test, should I have also explained that the Database is absolutely necessary for the system or was the fact I need to create a customer to run the tests with not clear enough

Comment: You are running a test - you should use a test database. Whenever you ignore that, test data will leak into production. Or destroy the database anyway. I understand this might be hard to achieve in your current situation, but you should try to do it.

Comment: @Sven i have added why removing the database is a bad idea in the question, also your suggestion still wont work cause the tear down isn't working when the test fails and i'm asking why it isn't working, even if your idea was viable and we just did a restore at the end of the tear down the problem still exists that the tear down wont work if the test fails so that means if we kick the test off at night after work hours and come back in the next morning and find it failed, we loose almost 1/2 an hour restoring the database manually rather than it being done automatically in the tear down

Comment: 2GB is huge. I wonder if this amount of data really is needed for the automatic tests. But anyway, you might not be able to change that soon. I think you should think about checking and possibly fixing the insert in `setUpBeforeTests`. Check if the insert that shouldn't be there is really absent, delete it otherwise. Or delete it every time, ignoring the error if it isn't there. And think about reducing those 2GB of data.